# Set div in unordered using css

Tags: html, css

I have more than 6 divs and I want to set it with float left and one after another with auto resize as per the content size using css
As per image below

here is my code:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">test1</div>
      <div class="content">Testing of css html Long Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">test2</div>
      <div class="content">Testing of css html Long Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">test3</div>
      <div class="content">Testing of css html Short Content</div>
    </div> <!-- And so on ... -->
</div>
```

[image: Set divs using css]

any help will be appriciate. Thanks

Comment: Using css it's not happen what you expect output. You should tried with JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all I know, you cannot achieve that using CSS only. The following CSS solutions are possible, but each of them fails to meet all your requirements.

### `float: left;` with clearing

This is all you can achieve using `float`:

[image]

For that to work, you have to `clear` the `float` every 4th element. Recommendation is to use

```
.container:nth-of-type(3n+1) { clear: both; }
```

### `display: flex;`

What you can achieve using `display: flex;` is similar, but all `.container` in one "row" will have the same `height` which will be determined by the "highest" `.container`.

### CSS `columns`

The only way I know of to create a type of layout like you showed is using css colums. *This does have the massive drawback*  that your containers will be stacked first in vertical order, and only if a column is filled the next `.container` will be pushed to the next column. So 2 will be **below** 1, not right of it.

### Javascript-based solutions

As mentioned in another answer, there's a load of solutions available based on Javascript.

Find the two mentioned before here:

> http://masonry.desandro.com/
>
> http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply but what i want is to set another 3 divs up and down as per the upper divs size.

Comment: As we know that my requirements will not complete within css, but as after you suggested me javascript-base solutions that are more useful, so i marked your answer as the right one for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use JQuery plugins like [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) or [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for what is you expected output. Using CSS you can not fill upper space.

You can also try http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/ which is very good using JQuery.

Comment: OP stated "using CSS", so imho we should make them aware of the options - and their respective drawbacks - they have. This is what I tried to achieve in my answer.

Comment: Still it's worth explaing *what* can be achieved using CSS only.

Comment: I have completed this manually like using 3 separate columns, where it is easy to set divs as i want, Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```
<style>
.main-container{
    border:solid green 1px;
    width: 500px;
    height:200px;
}
.container{
    border:solid gray 1px;
    width:50px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

By  using height  /width = auto can make your div flexible to its content as per your hint

hope this help.

Comment: This will set divs in unordered list like i want but still thanks for this.